Context deadline exceeded while REMOTE WRITE from Prometheus to vminsert
**
Before I get started this issue is related to remote write not scraping metrics from a server.**
I am scraping metrics of more than 100 servers.
But when i am remote writing it to vminsert I am getting following error :
ts=2024-09-10T12:10:17.827Z caller=dedupe.go:112 component=remote level=info remote_name=409e40 url=http://x.x.x.x:8480/insert/0/prometheus/api/v1/write msg="Remote storage resharding" from=272 to=500
ts=2024-09-10T12:10:59.892Z caller=dedupe.go:112 component=remote level=warn remote_name=409e40 url=http://x.x.x.x:8480/insert/0/prometheus/api/v1/write msg="Failed to send batch, retrying" err="Post \"http://x.x.x.x:8480/insert/0/prometheus/api/v1/write\": context deadline exceeded"

Below is my Prometheus config map file's remote write section.
    remote_write:
      - url: "http://x.x.x.x:8480/insert/0/prometheus/api/v1/write"
        queue_config:
          max_shards: 500
          min_shards: 8
        tls_config:
          insecure_skip_verify: true

Prometheus deployment file's args and resources are these

      containers:
        - name: prometheus
          image: prom/prometheus
          args:
            - "--storage.tsdb.retention.time=1h"
            - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
            - "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus"
            - "--storage.tsdb.retention.size=5GB"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 0.5
              memory: 4Gi
            limits:
              cpu: 3
              memory: 18Gi

vminsert file is like this :

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vminsert
  namespace: monitor-system
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vminsert
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vminsert
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: vminsert
        image: victoriametrics/vminsert
        args:
        - "-maxConcurrentInserts=4096"
        - "-insert.maxQueueDuration=15m"
        - "-replicationFactor=2"
        - -storageNode=vmstorage-0.vmstorage.monitor-system.svc.cluster.local:8400
        - -storageNode=vmstorage-1.vmstorage.monitor-system.svc.cluster.local:8400
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8480
          name: http-insert

Solutions tried :

I tried to increase the resource of vminsert but it didn't work.

I even made 1500 shards of prometheus remote write but it didn't work.


Again i repeat all the answers of context deadline exceeded here is related to scraping but i am getting it during remote writing.

Please, refer to https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#prometheus-setup. It recommends to set max_shards to 30, in order to get the best performance. Please try that first.

If it doesn't help, then probably the bottleneck is on receiving side - VictoriaMetrics components. Then follow this recommendation https://docs.victoriametrics.com/troubleshooting/#slow-data-ingestion

Your vminsert configuration also looks weird. Please remove maxConcurrentInserts, as it makes no sense in setting such a high value. This flag value is automatically adjusted to available CPU cores for the best performance.
It is also weird to have only 2 vmstorage nodes and replicationFactor=2. It basically means that every shard contains x2 of data. If you'd swtich to 2 VictoriaMetrics single-node instead, that would save you a lot in maintainance and resources, and will provide same functionality.
